# Native scrollbars inside absolutely positioned element

Tags: css

I'm having some issues with scrollbars on element with `position: absolute`. The behavior I'm experiencing is that chrome 21 and firefox 15 displays scrollbars inside the box, resizing it's content thus hiding some of the text, however opera 12 and internet explorer 9 displays it also on the inside, but without resizing it's content and resizing the box instead (which is in my opinion correct, since the box doesn't have width defined). Is there any solution to make this look the same in those 4 browsers?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kukkimonsuta/GaMD7/2/

Edit: as Siva Charan pointed out, it works correctly when overflow-y is set to "scroll" however that shows scrollbar always which is not desired

Edit: my final solution based on answers from [Siva Charan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500725/siva-charan) and [anonymous down voting is lame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144665/anonymous-down-voting-is-lame)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kukkimonsuta/GaMD7/15/

```
function updateAutoScroll(element) {
    var $element = $(element);

    if (element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight) 
        $element.css("overflow-y", "scroll");
    else 
        $element.css("overflow-y", "auto");
}
```

Comment: Is a tiny bit of JavaScript okay? I expect not, but perhaps it's okay for you.

Comment: JavaScript is the last resort, I would like to resolve this with html/css only :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this dynamically across all browsers is with JavaScript, for simplicity I used jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/mYuQx/

```
$(function(){

    // loops through each container
    $('.container').each(function(){                
        if(this.scrollHeight>this.clientHeight)
            $(this).children().wrapAll(
                '<div style="padding-right:'+scrollbarWidth()+'px;"/>'
            );
    });

    // gets the browsers current scrollbar width
    function scrollbarWidth() {
        var parent, child, width;    
        if(width===undefined) {
            parent = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:auto"><div/></div>').appendTo('body');
            child = parent.children();
            width = child.innerWidth() - 
                child.height(99).innerWidth();
            parent.remove();
        }    
        return width;
    };

});
```

Comment: Very well, something like this will do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow-y: scroll;` to `.container.two`

```
.container.two {
    top: 250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/GaMD7/6/)**

### UPDATE:

If you are comfortable, you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and replace `&nbsp;` to actual space

Comment: Well, it isn't supposed to overflow in the first place, that's the point I think.

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention that the desired behavior is to show the scrollbar only when there is too many items and the swap should be controlled by css only automatically.

Comment: @LukášNovotný: you can try using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: Horizontal overflow is not the issue I needed to display whole line. Those `&nbsp;` are there because I had another problem which broke each button into multiple lines, however that doesn't seem to manifest in this example.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than an actual solution, but it might be good enough. Basically, first wrap the contents of `container two` in another `div`, and add some right padding to it. Make sure you also set `width: 100%` in `.item`.

Here's a modified version of your demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/vbmEs/).

This isn't perfect, but I hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you, but this is still not consistent across browsers. Chrome and Firefox won't hide content (which is good), but Opera and IE9 will display excess space. Also the solution must be dynamic as I don't know at the time of rendering html whether content will overflow or not.

Comment: @LukášNovotný Yeah, I imagined that'd happen `:-|`. I think you'll have to use JavaScript, but I hope someone else will come up with a better solution because I'd like to know how to resolve this as well.

Comment: @Abody97, thanks for getting me started on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12353963/144665